# Why is this standardization of a normal distribution only using the estimated p for the variance?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I'm doing some old statistics exams for practice, when I found this task, crudely translated:

We have $$X \sim Bin(n,p)$$

"The random selection of size $n$ is large enough to approximate the distribution of the random variable $X$ with a normal distribution. We can therefore assume that: 
$$\frac{(X-np)}{\sqrt{n\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}}$$

is approximately standard normal distributed."

That is: $$\frac{(X-np)}{\sqrt{n\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}} \sim N(0,1) $$ Furthermore, they ask me to calculate a confidence interval, but that is not my issue.

First, a clarification. $\hat{p}$ is the estimated value of p using the given $X$ and $n$:
$\hat{p}=\frac{X}{n}$

I have seen a similar notation used as in the formula above several times when binomial distributions are transformed to standard normal distributions, however, not using $\hat{p}$. I cannot understand why $\hat{p}$ only replace the p's in the denominator. That is, why only the variance calculation uses $\hat{p}$.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from [Slutsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).  In this case, $\hat p $ converges in probability to the constant $p$ and $\hat p(1-\hat p)/(p(1-p))$ converges in probability to $1$.

Comment: But wouldn't the $\hat{p}$ in the numerator also converge towards $p$? Edit: Actually, reading the wiki article I think I understand why the denominator uses $\hat{p}$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It does, but think about what $X-n\hat p$ works out to!  To show  the stated result, it suffices  to observe that $\hat p \to p$  in probability (or rather, that $\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)}$ converges to $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ i.p.)  and that $(X-np)/\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$, by Slutsky.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{n\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}}$ as a [pivotal quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity) allows obtaining a CI for the unknown $p$ by rearranging an expression like $P[a<\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{n\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}}<b]$ into one like this:$$P[g(X,\hat{p})<p<h(X,\hat{p})],$$
where the left and right-hand limits depend only on $X$ and known quantities. If the unknown $p$ remained in the denominator, this wouldn't be possible.